# jUnit resets variable or keeps static variable

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, junit4

Currently I'm creating some Selenium Tests with Groovy. I have a separate test class for each section and the steps are the test methods. In the tests are running in a sequence to check the steps correctly. For the tests I'm using jUnit 4.11.

In my tests (e.g. login) I have a global variable email. This variable gets filled after the test creates an account extra for this test (the whole test class). I do this process in each test class to have a new account that works fine.

My problem is now that if I don't set email to static, jUnit rests the email variable after each test in the class. But if I set it to static and run another test (e.g. forgot password) it's still using the same email than before.

My actual question is, is it possible to not reset a global variable (not static) in a jUnit test?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the value of the instance variable to survive from one test to the next. If I remember correctly, JUnit creates a new instance for each test method run, so you cannot, you need to use a static variable. Also, in general, you don’t control in which order JUnit runs your test methods, so it could quickly make your test unstable. Do think twice. :-)

Comment: I'm using `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)` to keep the order inside a test. I guess I get around my problem with setting the static variables to private.

Comment: That sounds like the right way to do it (now that you insist that you want to keep the value from test to test).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should define your variable in a @Before method. So, at each test, your variable will be initialzed at first.

Comment: Like I wrote I just need the variable ones generated for a whole class. I think I found the solution, see the second comment on my problem